# Animate multiple views in a subviews with delay less than 1 second

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

just started to use Obj C for iOS,  I was trying to animate all the views (`UIImageView`) inside my subviews, but when I set the delay time to less than 1 second, the animation would animate all views at once. If i set the delay to 1 second or more, it will be animate correctly but the second animation will only start after the first one completes. I want to animate all those views back to back for example view number 1 would start animating, before it completes, the second should start to animate.

Here are my code.

```
-(void)animate
{
    int delaytime = 0.3; //first view will start after 0.3 secs

    for(UIView *view in self.subviews)
    {
        view.alpha = 0; //set it to transparent
        delaytime += 1 ; //couldn't get the desired effect when it is less than 1
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:delaytime
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                         animations:^{
                             view.alpha = 1;       // fade in             }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Complete");
                         }]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delay variable is an `int` and is therefore always rounded *down* to the integer value (0.3 becomes 0 and even 0.9999 becomes 0). This is the reason why all "delays" less than one second starts immediately for you, an `int` variable can't hold decimal values.

You should instead us the correct type `NSTimeInterval`

```
NSTimeInterval delaytime = 0.3;
```

Comment: Thanks David! really careless of me to miss out that detail. It works perfectly now.